# how to get userId followers and following list with instaSharp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, instasharp

i use instaSharp api to create an instagram web app
after i get token access i want to see followers and following list of my profile and another people profile
i need some method to Get another user followers and following !
in the official instagram web app you cant see followers and following list (just see amount) , So does this api support it ? How i Can do it ?
this api has a poor document and samples , 
How i can use this method ? [instaSharpDoc](http://instasharp.github.io/InstaSharp/Documentation/html/Overload_InstaSharp_Endpoints_Relationships_Follows.htm)

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can see user's followers and followings list with the official Instagram API.

https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/relationships/ - documentation

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/follows?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN - Get the list of users this user follows.

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/followed-by?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN - Get the list of users this user is followed by.

Comment: it means i cant get it , in instaSharp api ?

Comment: what is the {user-id} ? i want get it by username , user id is a long int number

Comment: You can get the user ID of a username, you can use this call: `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=[USERNAME]&access_token=[ACCESS TOKEN]`

Comment: yes i can get user ID , But this is the search result , in instagram when you search it search by name not username !

Comment: I can't understand what you mean, sorry.

Comment: in instagram api you can access to users profile with a user id such as : 12341564  not a normal username

Comment: ok , now i want to get another user follower and following , for this i need user id (not user name) . So how i can get it ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot request data from another user, e.g. followers and following, without the user authorization step.

Firstly, you need to redirect the user to an authorization page. After the user inputs his credentials, he will be redirected to a page(redirect_uri value) you have sent in the authorization request, where you will request the access_token to make requests on his account.

There is another option: you can add the username you want to make requests onto your app's Sandbox (require user verification). The username will receive a notification to authorize or revoke the access to your account. After authorizing it, you will be able to make requests on his account.

If you would like to understand more detailed information, please, have a quick look at the documentation about Sandbox at https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/. It will help you clarify your mind and your implementation code.

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

This solved for me using InstaSharper (without accessToken but using username and password for loggin in):

`var following = await api.GetUserFollowingAsync("yourUserName",PaginationParameters.Empty);
var followers = await api.GetUserFollowersAsync("yourUserName", PaginationParameters.Empty);`

This is the repository: https://github.com/a-legotin/InstaSharper

Tutorial to get starting: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f9leg398KAw

Comment: please add an explanation to help the OP *understand* the code you've provided; 
 please also add output showing the results you get, so the OP can more quickly assess whether or not that's the kind of output they were expecting

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is useful but for me it works:

```
IResult<InstaUserShortList> followers = await api.GetUserFollowersAsync(userToScrape, 
PaginationParameters.MaxPagesToLoad(5));

        for (int i = 0; i < followers.Value.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"\n\t{followers.Value[i].UserName}\n\t");
        }
```

It gives you back the username of all of the followers of a user (change UserToScrape with the one that you prefer).